# Cross-threading error/ Unresponsive UI

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a WPF application in which I have a MainWindow under UI thread. I have created a thread in which I create another window. I have to create this window in a thread because it has to be updated continuously. I want the owner of this window to be the MainWindow. So I am using Dispatcher.Invoke to set the owner of this window.

But when I use Dispatcher.Invoke to access Main UI Thread from Thread 2, I get a cross thread access exception.

I'll post some sample code very soon. Until then, if someone has any idea, please share it.

This is my actual problem to which I thought of implementing above mentioned approach:

I have three line charts with 4 line series each in a window which are updated at an interval of 100 ms which I am doing using Dispatcher.Invoke. Because of this, the UI becomes kind of slow and unresponsive sometimes

Comment: You realize that the need to update the window continuously does not contradict creating the window in the same thread as `MainWindow`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have created a thread in which I create another window.

That already isn't a very good idea and is prone to a lot of problems. All windows in your application should be created by the main "GUI" thread.

> I have to create this window in a thread because it has to be updated continuously.

There are ways to achieve that without creating the window on another thread. Create your window on the main thread, then use a background thread to update it. That background thread can update your new window by using `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

Comment: thanks for your response. What you have given is what I have  implemented currently. I have three line charts in that window which are updated at an interval of 100 ms which I am doing using `Dispatcher.Invoke`. Because of this, the UI becomes kind of slow and unresponsive sometimes

Comment: In general it's bad to access the UI thread from another thread, it's possible but it's bad.

You should do your 100ms stuff in a thread and just update your data structures. Then for example every 1000ms you update your UI with your data which are ready to be shown.

Comment: @Abhishek "user743414" is right. There is no sense in updating your charts every 100ms. Update the data that often - if you even need to do that - and update the UI periodically.